# How to move specific joint only using MoveIt?

Tags: ros, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using MoveIt interface to control my Yumi Robot either by setting  the joints value or the Pose values. What I need to do is changing the value of one joint only (joint-6) without changing the other joint values.

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277370/how-to-move-specific-joint-only-using-moveit?/) by [Ahmad](https://answers.ros.org/users/32189/ahmad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-12-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just solved it by some coding I get the current state of joints and copy them to a variable, and then just edit the needed joint only.

here is the code

```
std::vector<double> x;
group.getCurrentState() ->copyJointGroupPositions(group.getCurrentState() ->getRobotModel() ->getJointModelGroup(group.getName()), x);
x[/joint number/]=/value/;
```

The code is available in ROS book chapter 6
6.2 Planning to a joint goal

---

Originally posted by [Ahmad](https://answers.ros.org/users/32189/ahmad/) with karma: 41 on 2017-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1